# How to execute function after submit and page load

Tags: javascript

I trying to do simple registration form with error message for wrong data format. Till now I have index page with form, submit button that send the data to .js file where I make the validation. The problem is that I can execute function in the index page from the .js file and update my span message, but my page reload and I lose it. How I can make message that survive the reload or better to return the message after page reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use input onfocusout="myfunction(name.value) so when you click outside of the textbox where you typing you will get text that show you where you must to make changes if something is wrong. The problem with this is that now I must to have my code inside .js and in same time in my index page. It looks to me very fishy, but I saw this type of forms in many sites, but I am not sure how they achieved it with no using their validation code this way.

Answer (score 0):

If a button is tagged as submit, the page always reloads, this is how the submit property works. Unless you redirect it specifically somewhere, it would reload. My suggestion is link it to a database. Store the contents of text inputs, etc in a variable or a document in databases such as firebase so that even after the reload the data is stored in the cloud or on a database somewhere.

Since its a form, you're anyways going to have to store the data on a database so try out firebase / AWS and see if it works for you. When it submits, have an onEvent (HTML) or a variable and 2 if statements (Have an if statement to change a variable from false to true / other way round when submit is clicked and another if statement for the value of the variable to store the data), or any other method that works for you as this will make sure the data is stored so it can be saved after a submission.